# How to join 2 tables in Splunk based on shared column?

Tags: join, splunk, splunk-query

I'm sending Splunk 2 datasets that look like:

Dataset 1:

```
 - first_name: David
 - middle_name: Foe
 - last_name: Creek
 - job_title: accountant
 - jobs_finished: 10
```

and Dataset 2:

```
 - first_name: Alexis
 - middle_name: Stu
 - last_name: Ronald
 - job_title: accountant
 - num_jobs_must_finish: 20
```

I'm trying to join the two datasets based on the 'job_title'. I want a the returned result to look like:

```
 - first_name: David
 - middle_name: Foe
 - last_name: Creek
 - job_title: accountant
 - jobs_finished: 10
 - num_jobs_must_finish: 20
```

Any ideas for what the search query needs to look like?
I'm doing:

```
index="job_index" middle_name="Foe" | join job_title [search index="job_index" middle_name="Stu"]
```

Comment: what makes you think it's OK to assign the "num_jobs_must_finish" value from Alexis to David?

Answer (score 1):

Your query should work, with some minor tweaks.

```
index="job_index" middle_name="Foe" 
| join type=left job_title [search index="job_index" middle_name="Stu"]
```

If there is always one event being used from each dataset then `appendcols` may perform better.

```
index="job_index" middle_name="Foe" 
| appendcols [search index="job_index" middle_name="Stu" | fields job_title ]
```